# Is this the most efficient way to write this method?

Tags: java, performance

Newbie here, I'm writing a method that will compare two objects that store time.

I wrote this:

```
public boolean isBefore(TimeType secondTime)
{
    if (_hour < secondTime._hour)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (_hour == secondTime._hour && _minute < secondTime._minute)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_hour==secondTime._hour && _minute == secondTime._minute
                && _second < secondTime._second)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I feel that checking _hour==secondTime._hour twice is a bit redundant, yet without it the block does not work.

Because this is a three way logic tree (larger/smaller/equals), i could not find any real help on this matter, I was hoping to get a hand from you guys.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice in setting return value (use else or?)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/87965/best-practice-in-setting-return-value-use-else-or)

Comment: another possible duplicate: [Style for control flow with validation checks](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148849/style-for-control-flow-with-validation-checks)

Comment: boolean isBefore = hour.toMillis()<secondTime.hour.toMillis();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If speed is of utmost concern, store the `TimeType` internally as a single integer counting the number of seconds since a defined time (e.g. start of the day). A comparison between two `TimeType` objects then becomes a single integer comparison. Otherwise, it looks like you are optimizing code that does not need optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with TimeType (Google couldn't find it either), but my advice would be to convert (if possible) the TimeTypes to miliseconds and compare those.

This would remove the need to have nested if/else statements.

So it would become something like:

```
public boolean isBefore(TimeType secondTime) {    
    if(firstTime.toMilis() < secondTime.toMilis()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In case TimeType (again, I can't find the API for it) doesn't have its own method to convert to miliseconds, making a static method to do this is not very hard either.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove redundant hour test:

```
public boolean isBefore(TimeType secondTime)
{
    if (_hour < secondTime._hour)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (_hour == secondTime._hour)
    {
        if (_minute < secondTime._minute)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_minute == secondTime._minute
                && _second < secondTime._second)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add another layer of nesting `if`s

```
public boolean isBefore(TimeType secondTime)
{
    if (_hour < secondTime._hour)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (_hour == secondTime._hour)
    {
        if(_minute < secondTime._minute)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (_minute == secondTime._minute)
        {
            if(_second < secondTime._second)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

if you dislike nesting then you can alternate the checks:

```
public boolean isBefore(TimeType secondTime)
{
    if (_hour < secondTime._hour)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (_hour > secondTime._hour)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //here _hour == secondTime._hour
    if (_minute < secondTime._minute)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (_minute > secondTime._minute)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //here _minute == secondTime._minute 
    if (_second < secondTime._second)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (_second > secondTime._second)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```